# Sticky Navigation Causing extra Width

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hey guys I did made a sticky navigation bar for a blog. However I'm not sure why it's creating extra with, that allows the page to scroll left and right.

I've modified this part of the code that makes the page list sticky. I've put the with at 100% but it creates extra width space. How do I fix this? Or is this not the problem? The blog I'm working on is ..

```
.tabs-inner .PageList li a {
  border:1px solid transparent;
}
#stickynavbar { 
  position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 29px; z-index: 999; width:100%;
}
```

Comment: header doesnt seem to be the issue. Run this `$('#stickynavbar').css('width', '200px')`. Extra width still exists

Comment: @salniro Where do I put that piece of code?

Comment: I have checked your html. I think you have added min width in your body tag. if you reduce that and then adjust you menu width it could fix your problem

Comment: hmmm, still can't seem to fix it haha..